# Virtual Populate when localfield is array of Ids in mongoose

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, populate

I have a usecase where I have to populate data between 2 mongoose schemas whose schemas look like these:

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose'
import { Document } from 'mongoose'

@Schema({ timestamps: true, collection: 'notifications' })
export class Notifications extends Document {
  @Prop({ required: true })
  sourceApp: string

  @Prop({ required: true })
  body: string

  @Prop({ required: true })
  redirectionUrl: string

  @Prop({ required: false })
  metaData: Map<string, any>

  @Prop({ required: true })
  contactId: string

  @Prop({ required: true })
  isRead: boolean

  @Prop({ required: true })
  locationId: string

  // change to enum
  @Prop({ required: true })
  type: string

  @Prop({ required: true })
  resourceIds: string[]
}
const NotificationsSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Notifications)

NotificationsSchema.virtual('resourcesData', {
  ref: 'NotificationResources',
  localField: 'resourceIds',
  foreignField: 'resourceId',
})

export { NotificationsSchema }


// 2nd Schema
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose'
import { Document } from 'mongoose'

@Schema({ timestamps: true, collection: 'notification-resources' })
export class NotificationResources extends Document {
  @Prop({ required: true })
  resourceId: string

  @Prop({ required: true })
  data: Map<string, any>
}

export const NotificationResourcesSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(
  NotificationResources,
)
```

In the Virtual Part below,I am querying on resourceIds like fetch all the items from NotificationResources whose resourceId is in resourceIds array.

```
NotificationsSchema.virtual('resourcesData', {
  ref: 'NotificationResources',
  localField: 'resourceIds',
  foreignField: 'resourceId',
})
```

But the localField only works with single field not arrays,How to fix this? whats the workaround?

I am fetching data like this:

```
 async getUnReadNotifications(contactId: string, read: boolean) {
    const notificationsFilterQuery: any = {
      contactId,
    }

    if (read !== null) {
      notificationsFilterQuery.isRead = read
    }

    const notifications = await this.notificationsModel
      .find(notificationsFilterQuery)
      .populate('resourcesData')
      .exec()

    return notifications
  }
```